# Routing DNS requests via DNSMASQ

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dnsmasq

### Ubuntu 14.04 | dnsmasq

My goal is to setup a catch-all HTTP server using an Ubuntu 14.04 workstation as DNS resolver. I have installed dnsmasq on my Ubuntu 14.04 OS using `apt-get install dnsmasq` and I've confirmed it's running using 'service dnsmasq status'.

My goal is to route all traffic on the machine via dnsmasq.
In the configuration file for dnsmasq, I have the following:

```
interface=eth0
interface=wlan0  
address=/#/192.168.1.1
no-resolv server=192.168.1.1
listen-address=192.168.1.1
```

I want a scenario where opening firefox and navigating to *.com/net/org/etc pulls up a locally hosted site on my computer instead of actually having such requests routed through the nameservers configured in `resolv.conf` and processed by the corresponding DNS server(s).

Been at this one for hours. Any suggestions are welcome.

Update:
Thanks for suggesting a possible duplicate, while we're trying to achieve the exact same thing, my issue is that the changes in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` are not taking effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set up the local name server, but you haven't made your OS use it.

You need to edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` under your outgoing network interface, and add:

```
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1;
```

After that you need to restart your networking so that the new DNS settings take effect.

Comment: Thanks! Can you update your answer to reflect the steps to accomplish this?

Comment: This depends on your Linux distribution, there aren't any universal procedures for this. If you tell your distribution, then I can find out the instructions for that.

Comment: It's the first line in my question.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've added entries to my dnsmasq config to speed up page loads and cut out ads with additions like this:

```
address=/TARGET_DOMAIN1/127.0.0.1 
address=/TARGET_DOMAIN2/127.0.0.1 
...
```

These will match any path on TARGET_DOMAIN and respond with 127.0.0.1 as the IP address. Change that to whatever your inside web server's IP address is and you should accomplish your goal here

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, I used `address=/#/dest-IP` to route all traffic, # being a wildcard.